# LLVM GCC 4.2 error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type

Tags: objective-c, llvm-gcc

For this part of my code,

```
double Idistance = 10000000000;
```

Xcode 4.6.3 gives an error:

> LLVM GCC 4.2 error error integer constant is too large for 'long' type

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is clear: you declare a double and want it to hold a large number.

Double can t handle that number, use something else or find a way to reduce this number.

Also... Why the [] do you need a number that large?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
double Idistance = 10000000000LL;
```